# Does discharging of capacitor create sound?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits, capacitance

Today I found a wierd thing that as I removed the pin of the echo dot
[image]

And after this I removed the adapter from the power supply and found a wierd buzz sound coming from the adapter but as I connected this pin to Echo dot thinking that it would stop the sound and to my surprise The buzz sound faded with time and eventually died down.

So I know that the charged capacitor inside it is loosing its energy.
But what is the mechanism after which it is creating this weird buzz sound?

PS- I have original adapter and the voltage supply in my area is also constant.

Please try to explain it simply I am a high school student

Comment: If I've understood your question right, it seems much more likely that it comes from the transformer in the adapter, as opposed to the capacitors. This is usually because the adapter's a cheap knockoff, or your AC power supply in your area's iffy. I find it's often a combination of both :)

Comment: @Philip This is the genuine adapter provided by the amazon and the area where I am living also has a constant voltage and doesn't vary that much.

Comment: I actually want the mechanism and precisely the element which is creating this sound

Answer (score 1):

Philip is correct, as the charger is poorly grounded, what you are hearing is the [main's hum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_hum#Tone) produced by a [ground loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_loop_(electricity)).